# Device type Humidifier does not show the humidity

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, esp8266, google-home, google-smart-home

I've the device type humidifier working with Google Home and ESP8266 through firebase, I can query the temperature with google assistance but on mobile app it only shows the power button, is there any way to show the current ambient humidity? Any other trait is needed for that or it is a limitation on this device type?

[mobile app humidifier screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avDFJ.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

This is an expected result from the app as humidity is not a supported [touch control](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/touch-controls).

To file a feature request for new touch controls, use [this issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=655104&template=1284148).